# "class not key value coding-compliant [...]" when trying to reference custom view outlets

Tags: ios, view, outlet

I'm quite new in the iOS community, so this might be a dumb question. I'm trying to create a custom view with subviews that I can interact with in the code. Here's what I did :

1. I created a PageView.xib
2. I created a PageView.m and PageView.h files
3. In PageView.xib > Identity Inspector > Custom Class > Class, I put "PageView"
4. I dragged a label into the .xib
5. I control+dragged the label into the PageView.h, that has the code

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #ifndef LosAngeles_PageView_h
   #define LosAngeles_PageView_h

   @interface PageView : UIView

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

   @end

   #endif
   ```
6. Then I tried to use this View in a ScrollView I defined in the MainViewController

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

       // Get screen dimensions
       CGRect fullScreenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

       NSMutableArray *pages = [NSMutableArray array];

       // Initialize Views
       for(int i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++){
           // Create new Frame
           CGRect pageFrame;

           // Set x offset
           pageFrame.origin.x = i * fullScreenFrame.size.width;
           pageFrame.origin.y = 0;
           pageFrame.size = fullScreenFrame.size;

           // Get "PageView" nib content
           NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PageView" owner:nil options:nil];

           // Create view from the nib & set its size
           UIView *newPage = [nibContents lastObject];
           newPage.frame = pageFrame;


           // Add it into the Array & the ScrollView
           [pages addObject:newPage];
           [mainScrollView addSubview:newPage];
       }

       // Resize the content of the ScrollView (otherwise it doesn't scroll)
       mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(fullScreenFrame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, fullScreenFrame.size.height);
   }
   ```
7. Tried to run but got an error

   ```
    'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7a7dbb70>
    setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value 
    coding-compliant for the key label.'
   ```

What am I doing wrong ?

Extra informations :

- PageView.xib File's Owner shows "Label <-> label" in "Outlets" (only one here)
- the Label view shows "Label <-> File's Owner" in "Referencing Outlets" (only one here as well)
- All three files have the project ticked in the Target Membership
- Everything works fine when I simply don't reference the outlet
- Tried to clean, delete cache and other things of the kind.

Thanks for your time, don't hesitate to ask questions, and I can put the project on Github if anyone wants to see more precisely.

Julien

Comment: Put your code on dropbox.com or wetransfer.com so that we can check the issue you are facing.

Comment: Here you go : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x1teikfv2k3q1ca/AABGRVVx-wTnpQc4XeCWSpeYa?dl=0
Thank you ! :)

Comment: I am looking into it..Will respond it soon.

Comment: Alright I found the problem ! (Well at least I think I have)
When selecting Label, I changed the referencing outlet from "File's Owner" to "PageView" and now I can run the app. However, I still don't understand why it was false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the code here. I have updated the code with a new file "PageViewNew"

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eogulm5jkbsero9/losangeles.zip?dl=0

It is working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jassi, I'll go with your solution :)

Comment: Welcome. you can accept the answer. so that it could be helpful to others if they face the same issue.